# Button "Show only selected application" doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm struggling with Logcat. The button "Show only selected application" doesn't have any effect on Logcat's behavior and it keeps spamming me with all the device messages.

I know that it's possible to set the same tag for all the logs and filter by it, but I would like to use the full functionality, so I'm begging for your help. Does anyone have any idea of what to do?

[image: Just a random part]

Comment: I am rusty with my Android development and haven't used Android Studio much recently. This feature has always been pretty flaky in my experience. Looks like it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Yep, but it works fine for other people and used to work for me as well =/ I guess my current one is cursed :(

Comment: I typically have disabled/enabled ADB from the Android toolbar option to get it to work again. I use IntelliJ, though, not Android Studio

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, mate. Have already tried that. Still isn't working

Comment: In the event log in the lower right it says there are 7 messages. Maybe related to something?

Comment: @cricket_007 These were the old errors: it couldn't install the ADB when I tried to play with disable/enable ADB, but I've already fixed it, so no :( The app doesn't have any errors now

Comment: Which version of AS are you using?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 3.0.1. Reinstalled it, the issue holds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think "Show only selected application" actually does anything, I'm really not sure what it's there for.

My workaround is to choose `Edit Filter Configuration` (below the 'Show only selected application' option), then create a filter with the `Package Name` (e.g. `com.myapp.example`). At least this way you can filter messages from an entire package, hopefully this will suffice for your needs.

Comment: I've been having a ton of trouble lately with Logcat just stopping since I started using Wireless Debugging. Your trick fixed it this time for me! In the past I've had to disable/enable Wireless Debugging to get Logcat to start showing logs again, but adding the filter seems to be a much faster workaround.